# webkit scrollbar using jQuery.css() method

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, scrollbar

instead of this:
[source_of_example](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
var cssObject = {
'::webkit-scrollbar':{
    'width':'12'
},
'::webkit-scrollbar-track':{
    '-webkit-box-shadow':'inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)','border-radius':'10'
},
'::webkit-scrollbar-thumb':{
    'border-radius':'10px','-webkit-box-shadow':'inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
    }
}
$("#container").css(cssObject);
```

but for some reason it does not work :), please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.css()` method applies CSS **properties** to an element.

`::webkit-scrollbar-*` are CSS **selectors** that select pseudo-elements.
jQuery does not have any methods that interact with pseudo-elements.

Instead, you can build your own stylesheet.

Comment: ok, but loading stylesheet will overwrite my existing css properties  </br>  $('#container').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" />');

Comment: @PrzemysławBanaszek: Wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class with the `::webkit-scrollbar` pseudo-elements and use jQuery to add that class when you want to make your adjustment.

**CSS**

```
&.ipad-width::-webkit-scrollbar {
       width: 30px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('ul.scrolling-ul').addClass('ipad-width');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note on this: You DO need to initiate the use of the global selector, otherwise the classes don't seem to work. I'm using

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
}
.scrollbar.overflow::webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 30px;
}
```

to make wider than usual scrollbars appear only when the element is overflowed. Without the initial setting the default scrollbars appear and the class doesn't have any effect.