# html ::-webkit-scrollbar not applied via jquery

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, scrollbar, pseudo-element

I can hide the scrollbar in Chrome with:

```
# app.css loaded in <head>
html ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Now I want to manually hide the scrollbar, so I try to run the following with jQuery:

```
$("html ::-webkit-scrollbar").css("display", "none")
```

However, the scrollbar stays visible during scrolling.

How can I manually hide/show the scrollbar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [webkit scrollbar using jQuery.css() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232891/webkit-scrollbar-using-jquery-css-method)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Looks like there is no way to work with pseudo-elements directly with jquery. The proposed solution `$('html').addClass('hide-scrolling')` (adapted from answer) doesn't work for me though. Scrollbar stays visible. Is this how it's supposed to work?

Comment: Please check my answer with the working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this answer: [webkit scrollbar using jQuery.css() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232891/webkit-scrollbar-using-jquery-css-method) you can't work with pseudo-elements using JQuery but you can use a class to 'hack' it:

```js
$('html').addClass('hide-scrolling')
```

```css
.hide-scrolling::-webkit-scrollbar {
       width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```